# Present tense for future events

Tags: future, present-tense

Why does it sound perfectly natural to say *Our flight leaves tomorrow at 6pm* but weird to say *It rains tomorrow at 6pm*? What kind of scenario, if any, could make the *rain* sentence sound natural?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In continuation with the surety-prediction advocated in the other responses, you might also argue that we never know with a 100% confidence that the flight actually leaves at 6pm tomorrow.

The technically correct usage would be (and because the flight schedule is *present*) -

> "The flight is scheduled to leave at
> 6pm tomorrow."
>
> "As per the schedule, the flight leaves at 6pm tomorrow."

But for all purposes of common usage, the sentence you quoted in the question suffices for audience communication.

Regarding your query for the rain situation, the only situation where it would sound appropriate, was it coming from a soothsayer, an oracle or a psychic predicting tomorrow's weather. I guess it is within their business obligations to use such sentences to sound mighty-sure and give themselves an aura of invincibility against nature's vagaries.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. It makes me wonder if someday technology will have progressed to the point such that *It rains tomorrow at 6pm* would sound completely natural.

Comment: Some would add 'Our flight leaves tomorrow at 6pm, DV' as a 'technically correct usage'.

Answer (score 1):

Even “it **will** rain tomorrow at 6pm” sounds wrong, for the same reason Ham and Bacon states—it’s not a known thing. In the former example, though, you’re technically describing a *schedule*, something that exists in the present, so the present tense can be appropriately used there.

Comment: “It will rain tomorrow at 6pm” sounds bold, perhaps arrogant, but not unacceptable English.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is natural is because the fact that the flight *is* leaving tomorrow at 6p.m. is absolutely known for sure, whereas you are only predicting that it *might* rain. You can't be entirely sure that it is going to rain, so "will" is used to note that you are predicting it.

Comment: Then why does _the sun will rise tomorrow_ sound better than _the sun rises tomorrow_?

Comment: What if the sun doesn't? :)

Comment: Then pigs may fly.

Comment: Haha! [It's True! Pigs Do Fly!](http://books.google.com/books?id=FqSPKG1jJb4C&pg=PA1&dq=pigs+do+fly&hl=en&ei=ITfwTeTgK5SGvAOz8eyPCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: @Calli: I think adding a time makes it right - *the sun rises tomorrow at 5:38 am* which makes it similar to the flight leaving *at*

Comment: Thank you! The examples involving *sun rises* are quite revealing!

Comment: 'It is due to rain at around 6 in the evening tomorrow' is fine. Oops. //  The  actual departure of a flight is not a certain event until it happens. I'm not sure of the details hereabouts; I'd guess any rule someone comes up with won't fully hold. _Usually a safe guess_.