# Present instead of future?

Tags: future, present-tense

I keep noticing that native speakers often times use present tense when, to my mind, they should use future:

```
If you go straight, you (will) see a building.
I can (will be able to) give you $5 tomorrow.
I (will) start looking for a job and see what (will) happens.
```

Why present, not future?

Comment: In the last sentence, it's _start_ that ought to be future, not _happen_. The future is expressed with the present tense in all Germanic languages, including English. That's not strange, it's just part of how the language works. The more marked periphrastic future construction is often possible, but not always.

Comment: I'm sure there must be a duplicate. There are [strongly-linked questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29141/present-tense-for-future-events) at least.

Comment: It's as if words like 'tomorrow' take us into a future context from which we are able to use the present tense.

Answer (score 2):

For the first sentence, which is correct, this is called **tense simplification** in subordinate. See Swan, *Practical English Usage* or [this famous paper](https://books.google.ca/books?id=WVqlGOJvcgoC&pg=PA77#v=onepage&q&f=false).

In the conditional subordinate

future --> present

will go --> go